# Passing a value from a model to a view in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana-3

I have a model that fetches from my database a list that I want to be able to show in my view.

The model looks like this:

```
Class Model_services extends Model
{
    public function get_services_list() {
    $result = DB::select('*')->from('services')
            ->execute()
            ->as_array();
            return $result;
    }
}
```

My controller looks something like this:

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->template->title    = "services";
    $this->template->header   = View::factory('header'); 
    $services                 = Model::factory('services');
    $this->template->content  = View::factory('services')
                                      ->bind('result',$result)
    $this->template->footer   = View::factory('footer');         
 }
```

How do I render at the view the variables from the model?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually called the model method or passed the variable from your controller class to the view.

Change this:

```
$services = Model::factory('services');
$this->template->content = View::factory('services')
                                  ->bind('result',$result);
```

To this:

```
$services = Model::factory('services')->get_services_list();
$this->template->content = View::factory('services')
                                  ->bind('result', $services);
```

The changes here are:

- calling the method used to extract the relevant rows from the database.
- using the `$services` variable and binding it to `$result` which you'll be using in the view.

In your view you'll then be able to extract the values when you reference the `$result` variable.

To see what you've got from the model, test this in your view:

```
echo Debug::vars($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **services.php** use code as below ;)

```
foreach($result as $item) {
    echo Debug::vars($item);
    // print_r($item); //alternatively you can try this also, if Debug::vars() causes pain
}
```

Comment: thanks Kowser for the quick reply,  I'm using the template controller and now its giving me this error "ErrorException [ 2 ]: htmlspecialchars() [function.htmlspecialchars]: Invalid multibyte sequence in argument ~ SYSPATH\classes\kohana\debug.php [ 311 ]"                              i still dont know what am doing wrong

Comment: from my experience, the thing i can understand $item contains something which have unicode data, thus making that unicode data as multibyte sequence. You can try using print_r($item) instead of Debug::vars();

Comment: as you, it is just null, its better to investigate in your model. At least it should not be null, this is what i understand.